# Hide button if access rights in Accounting and Finance = Invoicing & Payments

Tags: python, odoo, openerp-7

I am trying to hide the button 'Refund Invoice' found in Accounting->Customer Invoices & Customer Refunds

[image]

If the user's access rights in Accounting and Finance = Invoicing & Payments. Except on administrator.

[image]

Is that possible ?
If yes, then how ?

Thanks,

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2395775/hide-button-according-to-group is this relevant?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to extend/override the invoice formular view. You can set groups directly on fields or buttons, which will show these things only to member of these groups. You will find an example [here](https://github.com/OCA/account-invoicing/blob/9.0/stock_picking_invoicing/stock_view.xml) where of course need to change something to set a group. For this example changing the group would be like:

```xml
<button name="%(stock.act_stock_return_picking)d" position="attributes">
    <attribute name="groups">base.group_system</attribute>
</button>
```

Comment: Is it possible that hides only if the Accounting & Finace = Invoicing & Payments ?

Comment: That's hard to do. Try to look into the accounting groups and set the higher group on that button. For accounting that would be "Accountant" with xml id `account.group_account_user`

Comment: The problem is solved. Thank's @CZoellner . Using this.....  <button name="%(account.action_account_invoice_refund)d" position="attributes">
     <attribute name="groups">account.group_account_user</attribute>
    </button>